# How do you avoid the lacheck warning when specifying half open intervals?

Tags: warnings, lacheck

I'm using lacheck. I have

```
Alice's and Bob's integers are in the range $[0, q)$
```

My LaTeX gave me the following warning:

```
']' expected, found ')'.
```

Is there something I can do to avoid this warning? I'm using an editor that gives inline warning, and this pops up in many places.

Edit: Also,

```
Number of `(' doesn't match the number of `)'!
```

Comment: Have you a complete MWE? I never have this case with the package I use

Comment: @RomainPicot oh, it seems to be a lacheck issue rather than LaTeX issue then. Will post something if I figured a fix for this.